# How to verify the text displayed on Jquery dialog using Capybara

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

How can i verify the text present on the Jquery dialog pop up box and click "OK" button on that dialog.My framework is using **cucumber**  **Capybara** with **selenium webdriver**.

Comment: I think the answer will depend on your page/popup. If you add the relevant part of your page's HTML and the code you have tried so far, it would make it easier to help answer your question.